# Fill color change on hover of a group of elements

Tags: svg

In svg on hover I can change the opacity of a group, how can I change the fill color of all members of the group? I would like to change the fill color of all members of the group when hovering over any element within the group.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    width="756.006px" height="576.006px" viewBox="0 0 10500 8000">


<style><![CDATA[
.region:hover
{

  fill: #00FF00 !important;
  opacity: .5;

} ]]>
</style>


 <g id="11" class="region"  cursor="pointer" pointer-events="all">
    <rect  style=" fill: #000000; stroke: none;"
        x="1990" y="2347" width="1866" height="1605"

    />
    <ellipse  style="fill: #FF0000; stroke: none;"
        cx="6011" cy="3239" rx="713" ry="768"
    />
 </g> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `*` selector.

```
.region:hover *
{

  fill: #00FF00;
  opacity: .5;

}
```

However, that is not the complete solution, because you will need to modify your SVG a little.  The reason is that `style` attributes on an element override CSS.  So you will need to either (a) define your SVG element colours as properties (see below), or (b) define them with CSS rules also.

So, for (a) you would need to do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    width="756.006px" height="576.006px" viewBox="0 0 10500 8000">


<style><![CDATA[
.region:hover *
{

  fill: #00FF00;
  opacity: .5;

} ]]>
</style>


 <g id="11" class="region"  cursor="pointer" pointer-events="all">
    <rect  fill="#000000" stroke="none"
        x="1990" y="2347" width="1866" height="1605"

    />
    <ellipse  fill="#FF0000" stroke="none"
        cx="6011" cy="3239" rx="713" ry="768"
    />
 </g> 
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XDvR9/